# How to access ref of Second child from first child within same Parent in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have Parent component containing two child component.

```
<Parent>
<Child1></Child1>
<Child2></Child2>
</Parent>
```

In Child2 component I have one `Ul` (unorder list), in which I have given `ref="mylist"`.

```
<ul ref="mylist" className="list"><li>Test1</li><li>Test2</li><li>Test3</li></ul>
```

So how can I access `mylist` from `Child1` component and get list values.

Comment: This might help for future reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

Answer (score 1):

You may consider to store values inside Parent component and pass them as props to children.

Answer (score 0):

use React.createRef() inside parent and pass that as prop to children.